# Do I have to pay the Internal Revenue Service in West Africa in order to transfer a government check from West Africa to a US bank account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, money-transfer, irs, scams

If you have a government check from West Africa and want to transfer the money to a United States bank, do you have to pay the Internal Revenue Service in West Africa before you can transfer you money to the United States?

Comment: Is a "govt check" coming from a prince or recently deceased millionaire and you need to pay taxes to clear the funds? What is the situation exactly?

Comment: Nicky, unless this is _your_ money you are trying to transfer out, you are being scammed. See for example, http://www.scamnet.wa.gov.au/scamnet/Types_Of_Scams-Advanced_fee_frauds-African_Development_Bank_.htm and http://news.softpedia.com/news/Scammers-Instruct-Potential-Victims-to-Contact-Bank-of-Africa-to-Receive-2-5M-302111.shtml and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerian_scam

Comment: West Africa is a [region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Africa), not a country, so there is no "West African Internal Revenue Service" and no "West African government checks." If someone asks you to pay them money to get funds out of West Africa, they're almost certainly trying to scam you and you should completely ignore them. See @ChrisInEdmonton's links.

Comment: Let me reiterate just in case it hasn't sunk in; *you are being scammed*. If you have a paper check in your hands from a country in Africa and you have not personally met the person who sent it to you, *do not deposit it*. If you have not sent this person any money, *don't*. If you have sent this person money by any reversible means (unfortunately they may have insisted on Western Union), *get it back*. Above all, *terminate all contact with the person with whom you are corresponding*. This person will tell you *anything* to get you to send money; *none of it is true*.

Comment: See also **[FBI: Common Fraud Schemes](http://www.fbi.gov/scams-safety/fraud)** and **[FSCO: Advance Fee Frauds](http://www.fsco.gov.on.ca/en/about/pages/aff.aspx)**.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - Curious as to the close reason. This question is a good opportunity to steer people away from those a-hole scammers.

Comment: @JohnFx I supposed that a question concerning a scam would be "not real", but I see your point. I'll reopen.

Comment: Wow, you'd expect the scammers to at least claim to be from an actual country. I think I'll send out a few spam mails claiming to be the Wizard of Oz, and I'm stranded in Oz and they have to send me some money, but then I'll grant them three wishes. Let's see how many people will fall for that.

Comment: @Lagerbaer - I read once that scammers make it preposterous on purpose; if a person *does* respond they are really dense and are less likely to figure out the game half way through.  Self selecting group of dummies

Comment: @MrChrister Any idea where you read that? I seem to recall hearing something similar, but I haven't been able to find a source.

Comment: @JohnBensin http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/167719/WhyFromNigeria.pdf

Answer (score 8):

No.  You *don't* need to pay the IRS *before* such a transfer – though you'll need to fill out certain paperwork to report the money transfer to authorities if it exceeds a threshold amount.  If the money is income, you'll need to declare it on your income tax return and then pay the taxes due.  If it is a gift, other rules apply and tax may be due.  Do proper due diligence and **consult with a trusted tax professional.**

However:   **Please see the comments above – this sounds like a potential scam.**

Comment: In addition, as pointed out above, West Africa is a region comprising a dozen countries. Probably not one of them has an entity called the IRS - each will have a different name for the tax collector. Some will definitely have rules about getting permission to transfer money abroad. Despite this, when all's said and done, the OP is in danger of falling for a scam.